# How to reset server state in Eclipse/JBoss Developer Studio

Tags: eclipse

Some days ago, my JBoss Developer Studio has crashed during a server was running within the IDE.

Since then, every time I'm starting my server within the IDE I get the following warning:

```
Server already running on localhost
An application server may already running on host localhost
Web Poller found a running server at url http://localhost:8080
```

If I select the option `Launch a new instance anyway` the server is starting and running without any problems.

I already made sure that no other application/server is listening to port 8080. And I also verified it with the `netstat` command.

I also started my IDE with the `-clean` option and I also execute the `Clean...` command of the server in Servers view.

Is there any way to reset the server state (Web Poller state) within Eclipse/JBoss Developer Studio?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I tried changing the port to 9045, but then got "Web Poller found a running server at url http://localhost:9045"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By changing Server State Detectors "Startup Poller" and "Shutdown Poller" from "Web Port" to "Management Service" I've solved the problem.